# Changing Workflow Status from Error Occurred to Completed using Powershell

Tags: workflow, powershell, status

I have tried to Cancel and Restart Error Occurred Workflows using powershell script and it works fine. But, now I want to change the status from Error Occurred to Completed. I tried to search a lot regarding the same, but I'm unable to find any information. Is it even possible to do what I'm expecting? Please provide your input.

Comment: You can remove the workflows that are having the status error occured and recreate the same.Let us know why do you want to do this?

Comment: We have a Sharepoint application and sometime due to slowness in the application, workflows gets errored out. So the expectation is that we should make that error occurred workflow as completed instead of cancelling and restarting the workflow.